# How would I find the current address using iPhone API

Tags: ios, geolocation

Is it possible to find the current location of an iPhone as an address rather than as GPS coordinates using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is take the GPS coordinates and put them into Google maps to get the address. It seems that Google has an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) that you can interact with, but I don't have any experience with it.

Good luck!